# Go to url contained in text file and execute Javascript

Tags: javascript, automator

I apologize for this vague question.
Workflow begins with plain text file. In the text file is url.
I have a working solution but probably not the best. I am on iMac 2015 running 10.14.6

1. Text file goes into Automator hot folder
2. Automator opens the file with text edit and extracts url.
3. Url opens in Safari
4. The page is a form with checkboxes.
5. Automator executes javascript in Safari to check a box

This works but the process is cumbersome. Automator has to launch TextEdit to get the url in the text file. Then it launches Safari to display the webpage and execute the javascript.
At the end of the flow, both TextEdit and Safari quit, and the folder waits for a new file.
So the programs keep launching and quitting continuously throughout the day.
Also I have to keep the jobs serialized. Automator will always extract text from the frontmost TextEdit document. So if I allow more than one job into the hot folder at a time, text files behind the front get skipped over.
Is there a way to avoid using TextEdit or Safari? Can you extract text inside a text file without opening it? Perhaps using Terminal commands, or maybe a single Javascript could do it all?
I am very new to javascript and not good at programming. This is a general question and I'm just looking for guidance.
Thank you.
[workflow part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLm81.png)
[workflow part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdopw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are describing something which test automation tool could do.
Try looking at Selenium, Playwright, Cypress...

All test automations can be written in javascript. They also support functions for finding element on the page and functions for executing events (like click event, etc.).
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page